# Unable to fine Alias Target even though S3 Bucket Exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to setup a static website on S3 and I'm following the tutorial. So far everything has worked and when I go to the long ugly domain that is the S3 endpoint I am able to view the website.

Now I'm trying to point my custom domain name to the website and running into a problem when I tried to create a Record Set. For some reason when I look under Alias it tells me that there are no "No Targets Available". I'm confused because I confirmed that my S3 bucket is in fact online.

Could this be because my domain name is not the same as the name of the S3 bucket?

Do I need time for the DNS server to notice that I changed the nameserver?

Could it be something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

In order to configure a custom domain to your s3 hosted website, you have to create the bucket with the same name as the domain. I have mentioned a screen shot from the aws documentation below.

[image]

You can get more info on this from the link below
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Comment: This is correct.  However, possibly worth mentioning: you can alternately create a CloudFront distribution and point it at the bucket, and configure the domain name on the CloudFront distribution while leaving the bucket as it is -- the bucket name no longer matters in this configuration, since CloudFront rewrites the HTTP request on its way to S3.  This setup also allows you to use SSL for the static site, which buckets with custom hostnames don't otherwise support.